# Qt creator 2.5 :Unexpected GDB exit , how do i know why the GDB crashed?

Tags: windows, qt, gdb, qt-creator

i downloaded the QT Creator 2.5 , using mingw that i downloaded from Qt site called : MinGW-gcc440_1
set up the paths in the QT Creator 2.5 and in windows global PATH .
im in debug mode when i compile , but when i try to debug with GDB
im getting this error in error msg windows : Unexpected GDB exit in title , the gdb process crashed .
im using windows 7 , 64bit , but the g++ is compiling in 32bit ,
i tried to search for some log in QT Creator 2.5 with no luck..

compilation line example :

```
g++ -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"c:\Qt\4.8.2_mingw\include\QtCore" -I"c:\Qt\4.8.2_mingw\include\QtNetwork" -I"c:\Qt\4.8.2_mingw\include\QtGui" -I"c:\Qt\4.8.2_mingw\include" -I"." -I"lib_json\include" -I"lib_json\include\json" -I"c:\Qt\4.8.2_mingw\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"c:\Qt\4.8.2_mingw\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\main.o main.cpp
```

ok i have log of the debugger but i have hard time to find the problem :

```
dATTEMPT SYNC
sStarting debugger "GdbEngine" for ABI "x86-windows-msys-pe-32bit"...
dStart parameters: 'LiveU_windows' mode: 1
dABI: x86-windows-msys-pe-32bit
dLanguages: c++ 
dExecutable: D:\dev\cpp\Qt\Qt_mingw\LiveU_windows\LiveU_windows\debug\LiveU_windows.exe 
dDirectory: D:\dev\cpp\Qt\Qt_mingw\LiveU_windows\LiveU_windows
dProject: D:\dev\cpp\Qt\Qt_mingw\LiveU_windows\LiveU_windows (built: D:\dev\cpp\Qt\Qt_mingw\LiveU_windows\LiveU_windows)
dQt: C:\Qt\4.8.2_mingw
dQML server: 127.0.0.1:3768
dSysroot: 
dDebug Source Location: 
dSymbol file: 
dDumper libraries:  C:\Qt\4.8.2_mingw\qtc-debugging-helper\ D:\Qt\qtcreator-2.5.0\qtc-debugging-helper\188129479\ C:\Users\meirmaya\AppData\Local\Nokia\QtCreator\qtc-debugging-helper\188129479\
d
dDebugger settings: 
dUseAlternatingRowColours: false  (default: false)
dFontSizeFollowsEditor: false  (default: false)
dUseMessageBoxForSignals: true  (default: true)
dAutoQuit: false  (default: false)
dLogTimeStamps: false  (default: false)
dVerboseLog: false  (default: false)
dCloseBuffersOnExit: false  (default: false)
dSwitchModeOnExit: false  (default: false)
dUseDebuggingHelper: true  (default: true)
dUseCodeModel: true  (default: true)
dShowThreadNames: true  (default: false)  ***
dUseToolTips: false  (default: false)
dUseToolTipsInLocalsView: false  (default: false)
dUseToolTipsInBreakpointsView: false  (default: false)
dUseAddressInBreakpointsView: false  (default: false)
dUseAddressInStackView: false  (default: false)
dRegisterForPostMortem: false  (default: false)
dLoadGdbInit: true  (default: true)
dGdbStartupCommands:   (default: )
dWatchdogTimeout: 20  (default: 20)
dAutoEnrichParameters: false  (default: false)
dUseDynamicType: true  (default: true)
dTargetAsync: false  (default: false)
dMaximalStackDepth: 20  (default: 20)
dAlwaysAdjustStackColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dShowStandardNamespace: true  (default: true)
dShowQtNamespace: true  (default: true)
dSortStructMembers: true  (default: true)
dAutoDerefPointers: true  (default: true)
dAlwaysAdjustLocalsColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dListSourceFiles: false  (default: false)
dSkipKnownFrames: false  (default: false)
dEnableReverseDebugging: false  (default: false)
dAllPluginBreakpoints: true  (default: true)
dSelectedPluginBreakpoints: false  (default: false)
dAdjustBreakpointLocations: true  (default: true)
dAlwaysAdjustBreakpointsColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dNoPluginBreakpoints: false  (default: false)
dSelectedPluginBreakpointsPattern: .*  (default: .*)
dBreakOnThrow: false  (default: false)
dBreakOnCatch: false  (default: false)
dBreakOnWarning: false  (default: false)
dBreakOnFatal: false  (default: false)
dBreakOnRaise: false  (default: false)
dAlwaysAdjustRegistersColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dAlwaysAdjustSnapshotsColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dAlwaysAdjustThreadsColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dAlwaysAdjustModulesColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dState changed from DebuggerNotReady(0) to EngineSetupRequested(1) [master]
dQUEUE: SETUP ENGINE
dCALL: SETUP ENGINE
dTRYING TO START ADAPTER
dENABLING TEST CASE: 0
dSTARTING D:/Qt/MinGW-gcc440_1/mingw/bin/gdb.exe -i mi --tty=\\.\pipe\creator-1832-26962
dGDB STARTED, INITIALIZING IT
<1show version
<2-list-features
<3set print object on
<4set breakpoint pending on
<5set print elements 10000
<6set overload-resolution off
<7handle SIGSEGV nopass stop print
<8set unwindonsignal on
<9pwd
<10set width 0
<11set height 0
<12-interpreter-exec console "set breakpoint always-inserted on"
<13-interpreter-exec console "set trust-readonly-sections on"
<14-interpreter-exec console "set auto-solib-add on"
<15-interpreter-exec console "set remotecache on"
<16-interpreter-exec console "maintenance set internal-warning quit no"
<17-interpreter-exec console "maintenance set internal-error quit no"
<18-interpreter-exec console "disassemble 0 0"
<19-interpreter-exec console "python execfile('D:/Qt/qtcreator-2.5.0/share/qtcreator/dumper/bridge.py')"
<20-interpreter-exec console "python execfile('D:/Qt/qtcreator-2.5.0/share/qtcreator/dumper/dumper.py')"
<21-interpreter-exec console "python execfile('D:/Qt/qtcreator-2.5.0/share/qtcreator/dumper/qttypes.py')"
<22-interpreter-exec console "bbsetup"
dADAPTER SUCCESSFULLY STARTED
dNOTE: ENGINE SETUP OK
dState changed from EngineSetupRequested(1) to EngineSetupOk(3) [master]
dQUEUE: SETUP INFERIOR
dState changed from EngineSetupOk(3) to InferiorSetupRequested(4) [master]
dQUEUE: SETUP INFERIOR
>~"GNU gdb 6.8\n"
>~"Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n"
>~"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>\n"
>~"This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\n"
>~"There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type \"show copying\"\n"
>~"and \"show warranty\" for details.\n"
>~"This GDB was configured as \"i686-pc-mingw32\".\n"
dCALL: SETUP INFERIOR
sSetting up inferior...
<23set substitute-path C:/iwmake/build_mingw_opensource C:/Qt/4.8.2_mingw
<24set substitute-path C:/ndk_buildrepos/qt-desktop/src C:/Qt/4.8.2_mingw
<25set substitute-path C:/qt-greenhouse/Trolltech/Code_less_create_more/Trolltech/Code_less_create_more/Troll/4.6/qt C:/Qt/4.8.2_mingw
<26-file-exec-and-symbols "D:/dev/cpp/Qt/Qt_mingw/LiveU_windows/LiveU_windows/debug/LiveU_windows.exe"
>&"show version\n"
>~"GNU gdb 6.8\n"
>~"Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n"
>~"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>\n"
>~"This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\n"
>~"There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type \"show copying\"\n"
>~"and \"show warranty\" for details.\n"
>~"This GDB was configured as \"i686-pc-mingw32\".\n"
>1^done
dPARSING VERSION: 1^done
d
dUNSUPPORTED GDB VERSION GNU gdb 6.8
dCopyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
dLicense GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
dThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
dThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
dand "show warranty" for details.
dThis GDB was configured as "i686-pc-mingw32".
dGNU gdb 6.8
dCopyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
dLicense GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
dThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
dThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
dand "show warranty" for details.
dThis GDB was configured as "i686-pc-mingw32".
d
dUSING GDB VERSION: 60800, BUILD: 2008
<27-interpreter-exec console "set target-async off"
>2^done,features=["frozen-varobjs","pending-breakpoints"]
dFEATURES: 2^done,data={features=["frozen-varobjs","pending-breakpoints"]}
d
>&"set print object on\n"
>3^done
>&"set breakpoint pending on\n"
>4^done
>&"set print elements 10000\n"
>5^done
>&"set overload-resolution off\n"
>6^done
>&"handle SIGSEGV nopass stop print\n"
>~"Signal        Stop\tPrint\tPass to program\tDescription\n"
>~"SIGSEGV       Yes\tYes\tNo\t\tSegmentation fault\n"
>7^done
>&"set unwindonsignal on\n"
>8^done
>&"pwd\n"
>~"Working directory D:\\dev\\cpp\\Qt\\Qt_mingw\\LiveU_windows\\LiveU_windows.\n"
>9^done
>&"set width 0\n"
>10^done
>&"set height 0\n"
>11^done
>&"Undefined set breakpoint command: \"always-inserted on\".  Try \"help set breakpoint\".\n"
>12^error,msg="Undefined set breakpoint command: \"always-inserted on\".  Try \"help set breakpoint\"."
>13^done
>14^done
>15^done
>&"Undefined maintenance set command: \"internal-warning quit no\".  Try \"help maintenance set\".\n"
>16^error,msg="Undefined maintenance set command: \"internal-warning quit no\".  Try \"help maintenance set\"."
>&"Undefined maintenance set command: \"internal-error quit no\".  Try \"help maintenance set\".\n"
>17^error,msg="Undefined maintenance set command: \"internal-error quit no\".  Try \"help maintenance set\"."
>~"Dump of assembler code from 0x0 to 0x0:\n"
>~"End of assembler dump.\n"
>18^done
>&"Undefined command: \"python\".  Try \"help\".\n"
>19^error,msg="Undefined command: \"python\".  Try \"help\"."
>&"Undefined command: \"python\".  Try \"help\".\n"
>20^error,msg="Undefined command: \"python\".  Try \"help\"."
>&"Undefined command: \"python\".  Try \"help\".\n"
>21^error,msg="Undefined command: \"python\".  Try \"help\"."
>&"Undefined command: \"bbsetup\".  Try \"help\".\n"
>22^error,msg="Undefined command: \"bbsetup\".  Try \"help\"."
>&"set substitute-path C:/iwmake/build_mingw_opensource C:/Qt/4.8.2_mingw\n"
>23^done
>&"set substitute-path C:/ndk_buildrepos/qt-desktop/src C:/Qt/4.8.2_mingw\n"
>24^done
>&"set substitute-path C:/qt-greenhouse/Trolltech/Code_less_create_more/Trolltech/Code_less_create_more/Troll/4.6/qt C:/Qt/4.8.2_mingw\n"
>25^done
>26^done
sSetting breakpoints...
dSetting breakpoints...
<28-break-insert -f "\"main.cpp\":17"
>&"No symbol \"target\" in current context.\n"
>27^error,msg="No symbol \"target\" in current context."
dATTEMPT SYNC
>28^done,bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x004014b3",func="qMain(int, char**)",file="main.cpp",fullname="D:\\dev\\cpp\\Qt\\Qt_mingw\\LiveU_windows\\LiveU_windows/main.cpp",line="17",times="0"}
<29info line *0x4014b3
>&"info line *0x4014b3\n"
>~"Line 17 of \"main.cpp\" starts at address 0x4014b3 <_Z5qMainiPPc+259> and ends at 0x4014d6 <_Z5qMainiPPc+294>.\n"
>29^done
dALL COMMANDS DONE; INVOKING CALLBACK
<30maint print msymbols C:/Users/meirmaya/AppData/Local/Temp/gdb_ns_.lY1832
>&"maint print msymbols C:/Users/meirmaya/AppData/Local/Temp/gdb_ns_.lY1832\n"
dHANDLE GDB ERROR: The gdb process was ended forcefully
dGDB PROCESS FINISHED, status 1, code -1073741819
dNOTE: ENGINE ILL ******
dState changed from InferiorSetupRequested(4) to EngineShutdownRequested(20) [master]
dQUEUE: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
dCALL: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
dPLAIN ADAPTER SHUTDOWN 20
dINITIATE GDBENGINE SHUTDOWN IN STATE 4, PROC: 0
dNOTE: ENGINE SHUTDOWN OK
dState changed from EngineShutdownRequested(20) to EngineShutdownOk(22) [master]
dState changed from EngineShutdownOk(22) to DebuggerFinished(23) [master]
dQUEUE: FINISH DEBUGGER
dNOTE: FINISH DEBUGGER
dHANDLE RUNCONTROL FINISHED
sDebugger finished.
```

Comment: Does it work if you compile in 64bit?

Comment: i didnt try to compile in 64 bit , i need it for 32 bit

Comment: Are you running the debugger on optimised code?  I wondering if you have a breakpoint set on code that has been optimised away.

Comment: i updated the question with compilation line example

Answer (score 0):

That gdb is version 6.8. IIRC Creator recommends 7.0, so have you tried to upgrade GDB?

Where did you get that GDB from? The one shipped in some mingw distributions is known to break when used from Qt Creator. You can grab one that the Qt Creator team thinks will work from here: http://builds.qt-project.org/